# Relating ProcessInstance in visualforce emails

Tags: visualforce, approval-process, visualforce-template

Demo for a visualforce email via Salesforce shows how you can relate fields - look at how Contact's email is included:

```
<apex:repeat var="cx" value="{!relatedTo.Cases}">
            <tr>
                <td><a href = 
                    "https://na1.salesforce.com/{!cx.id}">{!cx.CaseNumber}
                </a></td>
                <td>{!cx.Origin}</td>
                <td>{!cx.Contact.email}</td>
                <td>{!cx.Status}</td>
            </tr>
            </apex:repeat>
```

I am trying to do this for an Approval Process - Relating ProcessInstanceSteps and the ProcessInstance but get fails:

```
<apex:repeat var="cx" value="{!relatedTo.ProcessSteps}">
            <tr>
                 <td>{!cx.ProcessInstanceId.CompletedDate}</td>
                 <td>{!cx.StepStatus}</td>
                 <td>{!cx.Comments}</td>

            </tr>
            </apex:repeat>
```

ProcessinstanceID is the relationship field for the step to the process and CompletedDate is a field on the process, but this throws and error

```
Error: Unknown property 'String.CompletedDate'
```

I am matching the syntax, so i can't figure out why this isn't working. The processSteps without the other fields aren't very descriptive. 
Any help - appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the field that contains the ProcessInstanceId is indeed called "ProcessInstanceId" the relationship name is "ProcessInstance", so change:

```
{!cx.ProcessInstanceId.CompletedDate}
```

to:

```
{!cx.ProcessInstance.CompletedDate}
```

And it should work.

Comment: Do you know how to add the Step name? I was  thinking via stepnode  but this isn't relating, thanks

Comment: Sorry, I'm afraid I don't

Comment: No one knows how to add stepname